# Intellij System.out.println question marks

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to run `Hebrew` words by `System.out.println` - and i get question marks: ????

This issue prevent me to make if statement - check if string equals to something on Hebrew.

```
String one = "בוקר";
String two = "בוקר";
if (one.equals(two)) {
  System.out.println("בוקר");
}
//just for test the question marks:
System.out.println("בוקר");
```

I goes to `Other settings -> Default settings -> Editor -> File Encodings ->` Tried to put `utf-8`, and after this failed i tried to put `windows-1255`

Still, get question marks.

Comment: If you don't include any code or reproducible example this is gonna be tricky

Comment: @Dici i added to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @Dici - nop, also with equals - same results its return false.

Comment: This code works fine for me. And you're right, in this case even with `==` the string should be interned and it should return `true`

Comment: @Dici when you say "this code" you mean my code or the code from your link?  thanks

Comment: Your code :) It worked for me using Eclipse. Gonna try with Intellij

Comment: You should change not just the default file encoding. You should change the IDE encoding. And everything has to be UTF-8. Here is a [useful explanation with screenshots](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/).

Answer (score 0):

add

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

when you start the program